# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense errors in library files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm getting a lot of intellisense errors in included default header files:

Example:

```
5   IntelliSense: first parameter of allocation function must be of type 'size_t'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\new  55

15  IntelliSense: first parameter of allocation function must be of type 'size_t'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale  138
```

How can i remove these errors from the "Error List" window ?
But still see errors from my own project files.

Obviously I won't start fixing default VS2010 libraries...

**Edit:**

In a previous answer it was mentioned that something could have gone wrong in **size_t**'s definition. (It's not just **size_t** , but most of the errors are caused by **size_t**, and I'm pretty sure if i solve this i could solve the others).
Is there a way to at least find in which project in the current solution the error is coming from ?
Or, **what** can cause this to happen ?

Still looking for any lead to finding a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Has this always showing these errors, or did it just start? It's not the best solution, but I just had to reinstall Visual Studio 2010 to fix my header files. For some reason that I still don't understand, my entire VC/include folder had been wiped clean, and only 3 files were left in it. If something got corrupted or changed, reinstalling might be the simplest solution.

Comment: It happens in all the machines we have. It's not just a single computer running the solution.

Comment: I'll give you the points, cause it does solve the problem in a certain situation. And, I need to give them away anyway.